# How to write documents for Read the Docs in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip

I have found a great way to publish my documents online - [Read the Docs](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html). The problem is, their 'Getting Started' does not help much. Has anyone already tried and set up RTD in Ubuntu and so can provide me with step-by-step instructions? Please!

Comment: The guide you link to seems pretty decent. Are you having difficulties with any particular step?

Comment: installing sphinx ended up with some lines in red - errors perhaps. and I don't know how to create a 'directory inside your project to hold your docs: $ cd /path/to/project
$ mkdir docs'

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you didn't provide correct path to your project?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I don't know how to make a project and how to provide a correct path to it. And also, installing sphinx didn't go well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a folder for your project inside your /home directory or if you prefer you can create it on your desktop and give it any name (Let's say for example, Start ).
2. So you have to go to your created folder by typing in the terminal cd /home/username/Start.
   The command cd is intended to go to the directory.
3. And you will make there a new directory called docs.

   mkdir docs

   You can also do this all in GUI. Use nautilus for this. Create a folder 'Start' and inside it create a folder named 'docs'. Of course after this you will have to go to the terminal.

4 Type: cd /home/username/Start/docs

5 sphinx-quickstart

(username = your name which you use for logging into the system)

Comment: Thank you, and I have found a detailed guide for writing docs in Ubuntu for RTD (in Russian) [here](https://sphinx-ru.readthedocs.org/ru/latest/sphinx.html#id1).